# Laravel Scout - flush command not working

Tags: laravel, laravel-scout, meilisearch

I'm using Scout with Meilisearch.
I want to flush one of my models.

```
php artisan scout:flush "App\Comment"
```

returns

```
All [App\Comment] records have been flushed.
```

However, when checking out meilisearch, the records for this table are still there.

I think this happened because I manually deleted all records for the table in my database manually.

Answer (score 0):

Try this `Comment::removeAllFromSearch();`
Then cache your data again with `php artisan scout:flush "App\Comment"`

Comment: Sorry, to save is php artisan scout:import "App\Comment"